# Tag merge / synonym request: [software-performance] → [performance]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Please merge tag [software-performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-performance) (14 questions) into [performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) (461), and make them synonyms.

Tag *software-performance* has no wiki, for *performance* there is tag wiki excerpt:

> Questions related to improving application performance, this can be range from selection software architecture to selection of algorithms.

---

Preference for master tag is because it has much more questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good idea.

Created the synonym.

Not merged yet, though.